# How search and replace content inside {{:example}}

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

Is possible find a replace everything on a page if this is inside something like this: {{:replace_this}}

**Example**

```
<a href="#">{{:main_link}}</a>
<div>{{:some_content}}</div>
<p>{{:body_text}}</p>
```

to end with:

```
<a href="#">Home</a>
<div>Header 1</div>
<p>This is a body content</p>
```

I hope to do this with query and PHP where depending on the value I can change this content:

```
var X = [{main_link: "Home"},{some_content: "Header 1"}];
var Y = [{main_link: "Welcome"},{some_content: "Header 2"}];
var selector = true;
if(selector){
// change {{:this}} with X values
}else{
// change {{:this}} with Y values
}
```

Something like that and render the values using maybe:

```
$("body *").each(function(){
   $(this).html(value);
});
```

Just an idea.

Comment: You tagged php and said PHP, but you wrote javascript... so which language are you wanting to use for this?

Comment: both, because the content is generated on PHP but I want to replace with Javascript and I guess is not important the PHP part, just the way I hope replace some content, or not? i don't know XD

Comment: So you want to use Javascript to replace the content, so PHP doesn't seem to relate to the question.

Comment: You're right, I remove the tag

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can do that.

Save your HTML file with the placeholders in, then retrieve in in php like this:

```
$html = file_get_contents('/var/www/mywebsite.com/htdocs/html.html');
```

Then build an array of your search terms:

```
$search = array('{{:main_link}}', '{{:some_content}}', '{{:body_text}}');
```

And one of you replacement terms:

```
$replace = array($main, $content, $body);
```

Then perform the switcheroo:

```
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $html);
```

Comment: but this are my placeholder: {{:placeholder}}

Comment: You need a unique placeholder for each substitution you want to make it doesn't matter what they are though. whatever you put first in your $search array will be replaced with the vaule of whatever is first in your $replace array.

Comment: Yes I'm going to use a unique placeholder I just thinking if the $search array is not just a extra step that we don't need, Maybe something to find this: "{{:" and this "}}" and replace the inside content, i'm just throwing ideas

Comment: So you want to do search and replace, but search is a parameter you think you dont need?

Comment: jajaja no I mean the array, I don't know if is possible do it without that extra step, I don't mean that is not need, just if is possible do it with less steps

Comment: I gave you a 4 step solution, and you want to cut out steps? If you don't have a replace array then you'll replace everything with the same variable.

Comment: that's because the same placeholder is going to need be changed with more than 3 possible options and some of them are large paragraphs, I mean your option is good, don't misunderstand me

Comment: I think your database can cope with holding at least 3 possible options that are several paragraphs long.

Comment: Right now I'm doing something a little more simple, I just use `include('variables.php');` on the header and store everything inside like this: `$value1 = "value content";` and rendering with `<?=$value1?>` without search and replace, Im just looking for a "cleaner" way

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can target you element html adding #id or .class (for groups elements), here in PHP context we can talk about twig syntax.

```
var value = ["Home", "Header 1", "This is a body content"];
var i = 0;
$("#title_page, #content_page, #paragraph_page").each(function(){
   $(this).html(value[i]);
  i++;
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EwmywJ?editors=1111

Comment: in that case we can do something like this:
https://codepen.io/ozonostudio/pen/gGWMjW/

Comment: But i'm looking something a little more clean

Comment: because is some cases it's a large paragraph and I don't want it on the data tag

Comment: @oznostudio if your value come from a object json like {"body":[{"div":"content"}, ... ]} you can also do it by match a regexp value to only the string under { { sting }} ...

Comment: I wasn't using that, but it's a good idea too, originally I was using a php file where I store everything like this:

`$value = "this is my first value";`

and just rendering on the file with `<?= $value ?>`

Comment: ok because it trouble me  on how can you search for this {{value}} before the page rendering i guess you tryed to do by parsing an echo "<script> document.write(... " to your page but now ok it's a pseudo ref for javascript i guess :).

Comment: yes, I can do something like this: https://codepen.io/ozonostudio/pen/gGWMjW but its more messy

Comment: @ozonostudio yes is good like this is a data-value attribute pur HTML5. ty cya